# What is the proper way to implement AES CTR with 128 bit nonce and 64 bit counter?

Tags: aes, implementation

While encrypting AES in CTR mode, the input to the AES **encryption** function is the either a combination of IV + $m$ bit counter or is either $0$ IV bits with an $m$ bit counter. It is however rare to see the full usage of the input block ($128$ bits) as just a counter.
Since CTR mode essentially converts a block cipher to a stream cipher, the implementer must be careful that the XOR of ciphertexts should not reveal XOR of plaintexts. For this requirement, the $(nonce, key)$ pair should be unique for each invocation.
I'm particularly interested in file encryption, or a large (in size) session of encrypted communication over a network , (say file download > 64 GB).

**My encryption scheme:**
Use a 128 bit IV to populate the initial block. For every requirement of a 16 byte keystream increment the counter and add it with the initial block populated with the IV. (**EDITED**)

This will be the protocol: $C_{i} = AES_{k}(IV  + i) \oplus P_{i}$  where $i$ is 64 bit counter, $IV$ is $128$ bit nonce and $+$ is arithmetic addition modulo $2^{128} -1$.

- Is this secure (confidential sense)?
- Will there be collisions in the input
  block to the AES function since we have already populated the initial
  block, with random IV (Can modular addition of counter cause collision) ?
- Is this a standard way of doing AES CTR ?
- What is the proper way to check for overflow? Should I check whether initial block (treated as a big endian integer) equals to $2^{128} -1$ or only whether $i$ equals $2^{64} -1$ and then raise an exception?

Comment: Typically you need to include some integrity protection (to prevent an attacker from flipping bits in the ciphertext, and causing the corresponding bits in the decrypted plaintext to flip).  How do you propose to handle that?

Comment: @poncho For integrity, I will be using  HMAC SHA256 or KMAC... But I'm more concerned about the confidentiality and also avoiding nonce, key pair reuse!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be the protocol: $C_{i} = AES_{k}(IV  + i) \oplus P_{i}$  where $i$ is 64 bit counter, $IV$ is $128$ bit nonce and $+$ is arithmetic addition modulo $2^{128} -1$.

> Is this secure (confidential sense)?

Well, you didn't really specify the nonce to be random. If it is a serial number then it is obviously not secure at the next file uses the same block as what the other one started with.

> Will there be collisions in the input block to the AES function since we have already populated the initial block, with random IV (Can modular addition of counter cause collision)?

If it **is** random then you don't really know what the distance is towards the next IV. If you are (rather) unlucky then it is less than $2^{64}$ and then the really big files could be in trouble as the last part of one file and the first part of another may use the same counter and thus key stream. So serial number: clearly not secure

> Is this a standard way of doing AES CTR?

Generally the counter value and the nonce would use separate bits. You'd round up the number of required bits for the counter and use as many as possible for the nonce. Sometimes domain separation could also be encoded in one or more bits.

> What is the proper way to check for overflow? Should I check whether initial block (treated as a big endian integer) equals to $2^{128} -1$ or only whether $i$ equals $2^{64} -1$ and then raise an exception?

In your scheme you'd not really know when the overflow happens. In the general sense you could simply test if the counter returns to zero, or calculate the amount of bytes and make sure that you keep below that value.

---

You could also derive a different key per file, then you can use all 128 bits for the counter.

Let's describe such a system. $K_F = {KDF}(K_M, \mathbb{nonce}_F)$ where each value is 256 bits. Then start the ${IV}$ / counter at all zero so you can just perform $C = E_{CTR}(K_F, {IV}=0, P)$ and $C_{total} = ({nonce}_F, C)$ where $P$ is the original file and $C$ is the encrypted file.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112416/discussion-on-answer-by-maarten-bodewes-what-is-the-proper-way-to-implement-aes).

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to encrypt messages of size $2^{64}*16$ bytes before your keystream is reused within a message. This should suit your needs.

If your IV is randomly generated each time, you will need to consider the [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) for $H=2^{64}$ (64 bits). According to the table, if you encrypt 6,100 downloads, the probability of random collision is $10^{-12}$. This is still the case if the IV has lower 64 bits set, because that is equivalent to the scenario when IV is null in lower 64 bits and the initial counter $i$ is increased by the value of those bits mod $2^{64}$

Implementation is up to you but you can keep your IV and counter as separate ints then combine them. Counter will then roll over automatically. IV is an int128 and counter is an int64.

EDIT: There is no need to increment the higher 64 bits of the IV. This is not your counter. Don't change it. You have plenty of keyspace to use by only changing the 64-bit counter, as described above.

Comment: Yes, but initially the 64 bit int that represents the counter will be populated with IV's lower 64 bits, shouldn't I propagate  the carry to the higher limbs?

Comment: Actually, just noticed this assumes that the IV OP describes is null in lower 64 bits. Could add a proof that security is the same when IV has lower 64 bits set

Comment: And yes Viveknand that implementation note is inaccurate, will remove.

Comment: IV is not null in low 64 bits.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, implementation note is accurate after all; see edit. Also I adressed IV not null in low 64 now.

Comment: So, can I make the counter a 128 bit integer?

Comment: The counter is 64 bits long in this construction so it would make sense to implement it as a 64-bit integer. But you can make the **iv** a 128 bit integer

Comment: See, even if the counter is 64 bits, a carry to the higher limb is required, because, I want to encrypt $2^{64} * 16$ bytes of data. We are not checking whether, the last 64 bits of the *block* is equal to $2^{64} -1$ to detect overflow, instead we are checking another 64 bit integer that starts at zero and that gets added to the block that is always populated with the same IV for every call with counter incremented. If I were to check the last 64 bits of the block for overflow detection, then I would be able to only encrypt $(2^{64} -1 - IVmod $2^{64}$ ) *16$ bytes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112388/discussion-between-adrian-self-and-vivekanand-v).

Comment: Just an FYI, there's research that suggests you should limit the number of blocks below 2^64.  See https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/159.pdf (depending on your level of paranoia).